# Is $\sqrt[3]{5}$ in $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]{2})$?

Tags: galois-theory, extension-field

I am trying to solve question 3.7 (b) from Chapter 15 in Artin's book "Algebra".

The problem is:

> Is it true that $\sqrt[3]{5}\in \mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]{2})$?

It is clear by Eisenstein's criterion that both $\sqrt[3]{2}$ and $\sqrt[3]{5}$ have their minimal polynomails of egree $3$ over $\mathbb Q$.

Thus if we assume that $\sqrt[3]{5}\in \mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]{2})$, then we must have $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]{5})=\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]{2})$.

This didn't get me anywhere.

Then I tried the most simple minded approach.

Say $\sqrt[3]{5}=a+b\sqrt[3]{2}+c\sqrt[3]{4}$, for some $a,b,c\in \mathbb Q$.

By cubing and rearranging, it is likely that we will arrive at some absurdity.

But clearly this shouldn't be what the author must have intended.

Can somebody point me towards a slick solution?

Comment: Shouldn't something like this work? Assume that $\sqrt[3]{5} \in \Bbb{Q}[\sqrt[3]{2}]$. Then it must be the solution of a linear polynomial, but the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt[3]{5}$ over $\Bbb{Q}[\sqrt[3]{2}]$ is $x^3-5$, which by Eisenstein is irreducible, contraddicting the assumption. I'm not sure though, so if someone could correct me i would appreciate it :)

Comment: @Ale The polynomial $x^3-5$ sure is irreducible over $\mathbb Q$ (by Eisenstein). But we can't say that same for $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]{2})$. At least not by Eisenstein's. As least not in a trivial way.

Comment: You are right, thank you, such an argument works only to show that irrational numbers do not belong in $\Bbb{Q}$ as Einstein applies only there.

Comment: your simple long winded approach works and I believe that you will get your absurdity with a system of equations.  I can't provide a slicker method though.

Comment: Your solution is likely the expected one. Certainly the one below is not appropriate for Artin.

Comment: There is an elementary solution, which involves the use of the trace and the norm of elements of a field extension. It is very funny according to me. You can read [this](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/galoistheory/tracenorm.pdf) until page $6$ and there you have an example which shows that $\sqrt[3]{3}\notin \Bbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$. Similarly you can show your claim. Hope that helps. I was thinking to write an answer, but the steps needed to show your claim are practically the same as the one used by Conrad in the example at page 6.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It depends how much Galois Theory you want to use. I will show that $\sqrt[3]{5} \not \in \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[3]{2}, \omega],$ where $\omega$ is a primitive complex cube  of unity, and the cube roots are assumed to be the real ones. Suppose otherwise.
Note that the last field (over $\mathbb{Q}$) has order $6$ and is generated by two automorphisms: one, say $\sigma,$ interchanges $\omega$ and $\omega^{2}$ and fixes every element of $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[3]{2}].$ The other, say $\tau$ sends $\sqrt[3]{2}$ to $\omega \sqrt[3]{2}$ and sends $\omega \sqrt[3]{2}$ to $\omega^{2} \sqrt[3]{2}$ (and therefore fixes $\omega$ and $\omega^{2})$ and sends $\omega^{2} \sqrt[3]{2}$ to $\sqrt[3]{2}.$

Let's see where $\tau$ can send $\sqrt[3]{5}$. It can't fix $\sqrt[3]{5}$ or it would fix the whole real subfield of $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[3]{2}, \omega],$ and it already fixes $\omega$ and $\omega^{2}$, so it would be the trivial automorphism. It must send $\sqrt[3]{5}$ to another cube root of $5$ though.

Suppose that $\tau(\sqrt[3]{5}) = \omega \sqrt[3]{5}.$ Then $\tau$ and $\sigma$ both fix
$\frac{\sqrt[3]{5}}{\sqrt[3]{2}}$, so $\frac{\sqrt[3]{5}}{\sqrt[3]{2}} \in \mathbb{Q}$, which is quickly seen to contradict unique factorization in $\mathbb{Z}$ ( if $b\sqrt[3]{5} = a\sqrt[3]{2}$ for relatively prime integers $a$ and $b,$ then $5b^{3} = 2a^{3},$ so $5$ divides $a$ and then $5$ divides $b,$ a contradiction).

Suppose then that $\tau(\sqrt[3]{5}) = \omega^{2} \sqrt[3]{5}.$ Then $\tau(\sqrt[3]{25}) = \omega \sqrt[3]{25}.$ Now, however, $\tau$ and $\sigma$ both fix
$\frac{\sqrt[3]{25}}{\sqrt[3]{2}}$, so $\frac{\sqrt[3]{25}}{\sqrt[3]{2}} \in \mathbb{Q}$, which is again quickly seen to contradict unique factorization in $\mathbb{Z}$ ( if $b\sqrt[3]{25} = a\sqrt[3]{2}$ for relatively prime integers $a$ and $b,$ then $25b^{3} = 2a^{3},$ so $5$ divides $a$ and then $5$ divides $b,$ a contradiction).

Hence  the assumption that $\sqrt[3]{5} \in \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[3]{2}, \omega]$ leads to a contradiction in any case.

Comment: Nice argument. You have some typos: fix 2 to 5 and 4 to 25 in the beginnings of paragraphs 3 and 4.

Answer (score 5):

Not an elementary answer, but $\Bbb Q(\root3\of2\,)$ is ramified over $\Bbb Q$ only at $2$ and $3$; $\root3\of5$ requires ramification at $5$.

**EDIT**: Perhaps a more convincing argument (I'll use the notation $\lambda=\root3\of2$):

It’s “well known” that $\Bbb Z[\lambda]$ is the integer ring of $\Bbb Q(\lambda)$, and that this ring is PID (the class number is $1$). But we have a clear factorization of $5$ there, namely
$$
5 = (1+\lambda^2)(1 + 2\lambda - \lambda^2)\,.
$$
You can check that the first factor has norm $5$, the second one has norm $25$. In any event, neither is a unit, so by Eisenstein, $X^3-5$ is irreducible over $\Bbb Q(\root3\of2\,)$.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that $\sqrt[3]{5}$ belongs to $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$, then for every prime $p\equiv 1\pmod{3}$ such that $2$ is a cubic residue, also $5$ is a cubic residue. However, there are an infinite number of primes for which that does not hold, the first of them being $31$. $x^3-2$ splits as $(x-4)(x-7)(x+11)$ over $\mathbb{F}_{31}$, while $x^3-5$ is an irreducible polynomial. It follows that $\sqrt[3]{5}\not\in\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$, as expected.

Comment: I don't think this works if the coefficients of $\sqrt[3]5$ are rationals with some $p$ in their denominator. That's why i went to the trouble of restricting the possible denominators. Sure there are an infinite number of primes like that but that's a bit more high level.

Comment: @Jack Can you please explain the reasoning behind the fact that "if $\sqrt[3]{5}\in\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]{2})$, then for every prime $p\equiv 1\pmod{3}$ such that $2$ is a cubic residue of $p$, $5$ is also a cubic residue of $p$."

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $\Bbb Q(\sqrt[3]2) = \Bbb Q(\sqrt[3]5)$.

Let $R = \Bbb Z[\sqrt[3]2]$ and $O$ be the ring of integers of $\Bbb Q(\sqrt[3]2)$.
We obviously have that $O$ contains $R$, and since $\sqrt[3]5$ is an algebraic integer , it is in $O$.

The fundamental volume for $R$ is the square root of the absolute value of the discriminant of $X^3-2$, so it is $6\sqrt 3$.

Since the fundamental volume for $O$ is the square root of an integer, the index of $O$ in $R$ is a divisor of $6$, and so $R \subset O \subset \frac 16 R$. Hence $\sqrt[3]5 \in \frac 16 R$, so $5 = \left(\frac{a+b\sqrt[3]2+c\sqrt[3]4}6\right)^3$ for some integers $a,b,c$.

However $31$ is a prime not dividing $6$ and modulo which $2$ is a cube and $5$ isn't,  so we obtain a contradiction by looking at this relation modulo $31$.

Comment: Thank you for your post. But this to advanced for me to understand.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an approach that is less elegant but more elementary than the answers so far: we examine the minimal polynomial of some algebraic combination of $\sqrt[3]{2}$ and $\sqrt[3]{5}$.

For example, $\sqrt[3]{2} + \sqrt[3]{5}$ satisfies the polynomial $x^9 - 21x^6 -123x^3  -343$, so we are done if we can show that this polynomial is irreducible.  This is not so easy to do by hand, of course.

Comment: It's tedious but straightforward. I may try it later on to see how long it takes, but I doubt it is more than 30 minutes.